# Error with Images

Tags: java

I recently finished the basics of a game that I'm making and I was going to send it to some friends, but whenever they open the .jar it's just a grey window.  When I heard that I assumed it was because of the way I got the images  (I used a full path: C:\Users\etc).  I did some Googling and found a way to get images that seemed more efficient.

```
private static Image[] mobImages =  new Image[1];

public static void loadImages()
{
     mobImages[1] = Handler.loadImage("res/EnemyLv1.png");
}

public static Image getMobImages(int index)
{
     return mobImages[index];
}
```

That's what I would like to use.  But I did that and changed the rest of my code to support that.  And whenever I run a game I get a few errors.  Which all point back to

this:
if(getBounds().intersects(tempEnemy.getBounds()))

and so probably the way I'm getting the images too.  How could I fix this?  And are there better ways to get Images?  I've tried a few but they haven't worked.

EDIT:  I finally solved all of the errors! :D  The only problem is that none of the images appear. Here's [my code](http://www.mediafire.com/?uykkdp0nzdi9092) again.  Any more help?  That would be fantastic!  Thanks everybody for the support so far!

Comment: Exactly what errors do you get? Knowing this would make debugging a lot easier.

Comment: Well, when the game starts the background is drawn, and so is the player, but you can't move, and enemies don't appear.  This error says:  Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: I guess you get a NullpointerException. But we need more information on 1. the exception and 2. what does Handler.loadImage do. Hint: We need the code, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say whats going wrong in your code. However I recommend you put your *image files* into a package in the java project (so they will be part of the JAR file) and access them using Class.getResource()/Class.getResourceAsStream(). That avoids multiple pitfalls and keeps everything together.

A sample how to structure your images into the packages:

> myproject
>     images
>       ImageLocator.class
>       MyImage1.jpg
>       MyImage2.jpg

The ImageLocator class then needs to use relative pathes (just the image name + extension) to access to resources.

```
public class ImageLocator {
    public final static String IMAGE_NAME1 = "MyImage1.jpg";

    public static Image getImage(final String name) {
        URL url = ImageLocator.class.getResource(name);
        Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(url);
        // ensure the image is loaded
        return new ImageIcon(image).getImage();            
    }
}
```

This can be done more elegant, but this should get you started. Defining the image names as constants in the ImageLocator class avoids spreading the concrete path throughout the project (as long as the name is correct in ImageLocator, everything else will be checked by the compiler)

Comment: Ok, so I would just make a new getImage method for every new image?  Also, how would I refer to the images?  Since I do that in my getBounds() method.

Comment: ImageLocator.getImage(ImageLocator.IMAGE_NAME1) would get you image #1. You just define a new name for every image in ImageLocator. For best performance I would load all the images once through this method and then keep them cached somewhere. Of course the name constants *should* be chosen so the name tells what the image is (like IMAGE_ENEMY1, IMAGE_PLAYER etc.)

Comment: When I type in getResourceURL(name);  It says that I need to create a method?

Comment: My bad, copied the code from my codebase and missed that getResource() is on the class, not the object itself. Fixed code sample.

Answer (score 0):

Your code still uses "C:\Users\Kids\Desktop\Java Game\Cosmic Defense\res\EnemyLv2.png" in Enemy.java. Are you sure this exists? If you moved the Cosmic Defense folder, it will not.

(You were talking about changing absolute paths to relative paths, so this may be your problem)

Answer (score 0):

Part of the reason could be that your code is pointing to an index of "1" in an array of size 1, meaning that the only available index is in fact "0".

Try `mobImages[0] = Handler.loadImage("res/EnemyLv1.png");`

Comment: It's not going to be the whole problem solved, but it will definitely be part of why it's not working.

Comment: Yeah tried it, it didn't fix the whole problem but at least I know I'm making progress.  The console points to my checkCollisions method.  Could somebody please check my code and help me solve the problem?